# White pixel irregularly appears/disappears on Windows 11 + disappears on mouse over

Tags: windows-11, lenovo-laptop, mouse-cursor, stuck-pixel, nvidia-rtx

I'm puzzled.

I have been doing some gaming on my Lenovo laptop lately and two days ago I noticed a white pixel on my Windows 11 desktop. Moving a dark background window over/under that pixel actually revealed this.

At first I thought this is a hardware issue with my monitor (stuck pixel), but when I noticed the white pixel disappearing irregularly, I thought this is not monitor-related. Restarting Windows 11 usually fixes the white pixel for a while, but at some point, it just comes back:

[image]

I was completely confused when I was moving the mouse cursor over the white pixel, which made/makes the white pixel disappear. I changed the mouse cursor to a black one for better confirmation:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be here?

Is it a problem with some graphics card buffer being corrupted (Nvidia RTX A4000)? Some other buffer with Windows? I doubt Windows is still using any buffers itself, given that my Lenovo is approximately one year old and they're all using hardware acceleration for just about anything... -> it's a Lenovo P71 from 2022 to be precise.

**EDIT:**

Monitor is a Dell U4021QW.

Comment: Reminds me of the cracked cell phone background... If the pixel disappears under the mouse, and the mouse is the same black color as the terminal window, that sounds like a weird software issue... Is there a way to use a different video driver, even a basic one temporarily? If you've still got any warranty left, inquire with the manufacturer about getting it fixed (or replaced :) for free

Comment: Update your graphics card drivers, and see if the issue persists. If it does, factory reset the graphics settings in the NVidia control panel.

Comment: You could also do some testing with another OS like Ubuntu. If the same kind of thing / other graphical corruption happens then there is probably something wrong with your GPU

Comment: What is the monitor?

Comment: Thanks for the tips so far. See my edit for monitor model.

Comment: Try a live USB (an operating system you do not have to install) and if the issue is only on Windows you can run an Autoit script like https://pastebin.com/SS1B65Q8 that shows you which windows exist and which PID they are linked to.

Comment: Might be a weak pixel getting stuck on white. Jiggling the display of a stuck pixel can sometimes help for some time.

Comment: Two things to try: 1. If the issue is *only* in Windows on main drive  (not when booting from USB), look in Task Manager for some errant process/service. 2. If the issue occurs under other OS, try an app like IsMyLcdOK , https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK, to "exercise" LCD pixels. It might, or might not, help.

Comment: can you try right clicking on the pixel to see if you get a "restore move resize menu"